# Curl Zip file and extract data php

Tags: php, csv, curl, zip

I am able to retrieve a file and was expecting a CSV, but instead it is a zip file.  I there a way to take the zip I'm retrieving and getting the CSV out of it on the fly? If so how? If not what's the best method? I searched and found a topic 6 yrs old with now responses.

```
function get_data_zip($url){
//echo $url;exit;
  $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "X-App-Key: xxx";
$headers[] = "X-User-Key: yyy";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);}
```

Comment: yes - google it. http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't answer if it can be done in memory, but I'm working towards that was just hoping for a shortcut.  Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix!

Comment: you have to, open the zip, find the file and use the stream output wrapper. `$Zip->getStream( 'file' )`  http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstream.php  That will give you a file handle just like `fopen` etc.

Comment: In the case of reading it as a CSV just take the file handle and feed it into `$h = $Zip->getStream( 'file' );  $csv = fgetcsv( $h );` ect..

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate it, I'm hoping to have it finished up shortly thanks to your help!

Comment: Sure, just think of a Zip file like a special kind of folder and not a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick example

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open('test.zip')) {
    $fp = $z->getStream('test');
    if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $csv = fgetcsv($fp);
        var_dump( $csv );
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstream.php

You will need to use something like this to get the name of the files in the zip folder

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $z->numFiles; $i++) {
    $name = $z->getNameIndex($i);
    // ...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getnameindex.php

It depends though if you expect only one file,  in there, is it always named the same way, or can there be multiple files you have to process, these things I cannot answer.

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open('test.zip')) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $z->numFiles; $i++) {
        $name = $z->getNameIndex($i);
        $fp = $z->getStream($name);
        if(!$fp) exit("failed on $name\n");

        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $csv = fgetcsv($fp);
            //.. do some other stuff ( save in DB etc. )
            var_dump( $csv );
        }//end while not end of file
    }//end for files 
}//end open zip
```

Comment: The last bit of code worked perfectly thanks again for your patience and Help @ArtisticPhoenix